# verbatim text in ConTeXt tables

Tags: tables, verbatim, context

I want to create a table for a few blocks of source code. In LaTeX, I would do

```
\hline 
\begin{lstlisting}
abc;
def;
\end{lstlisting}
\tabularnewline
```

Is there a way to accomplish something like this in ConTeXt? I have tried `\starttyping` and `\stoptyping` within table cells, but the file fails to compile if I do that.

The reason I would like to use tables is that I could then use `\placetable` for floats, and also that I would have a clean way of referring to it in other parts of the document.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use buffers. Store the content in a buffer using

```
\startbuffer[...] 
  ...
\stopbuffer
```

and retrieve it using `\typebuffer`. Here is a simple example with tables.

```
\startsetups table:setup
  \setupTABLE[each][each][frame=off]
  \setupTABLE[row][first][style=bold,color=white,background=color,backgroundcolor=black]
  \setupTABLE[row][last][bottomframe=on, framethickness=3bp]
\stopsetups
\starttext

\startbuffer[CPP]
#include <iostream.h>

void main()
{
  cout << "Hello World\n";
}
\stopbuffer

\startbuffer[ruby]
puts "Hello World"
\stopbuffer

\startTABLE[setups=table:setup]
  \NC C++                \NC Ruby              \NC \NR
  \NC \typebuffer[CPP]   \NC \typebuffer[ruby]  \NC \NR
\stopTABLE
\stoptext
```

which gives

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The first thing: Verbatin text in tables work:

```
\starttext

\starttabulate
    \NC Foo        \NC Bar \NC\AR
    \NC \type{Foo} \NC Bar \NC\AR
\stoptabulate

\bTABLE
    \bTR
        \bTD Foo \eTD
        \bTD Bar \eTD
    \eTR
    \bTR
        \bTD Foo        \eTD
        \bTD \type{Bar} \eTD
    \eTR
\eTABLE

\stoptext
```

Result:
[image: firstresult]

The second thing is that you don't need a table to refer to your code. You can create your own floating type. However even that doesn't have to float. The following code creates a custom floating evironment, not perfect, but hopefully enough to get you started.

```
\definefloat [code] [codes]

\starttext

\input knuth

As illustrated in \in{code}[code:example].

\startplacecode [title=Some example code., reference=code:example]
    \starttyping
        int main(){
            return 0;
        }
    \stoptyping
\stopplacecode

\stoptext
```

It looks like this:

[image: secondresult]

Comment: Your first answer works only with single line text, so I can't use it. I like your second answer, and will use it later. For the moment, though, I need tables.

Comment: If you need more text, then buffers is the way to go, see Adityas anwser.